# What is the origin of the phrase "thank bog"?

Tags: etymology, slang

I sometimes use this phrase, and I have no recollection where I first heard it.  I know I've heard other people use it as well, and a search on google shows references to it dating back to at least the early 2000's (frequently on blogs or other informal resources).

I recently made this comment to my wife, and she said she had never heard of it before.

Where and when did this phrase originate?

Comment: Never heard of it before, though I have seen a few similar formations.  I'd assume that it was a somewhat jocular attempt at taking the Lord's name in vain without taking the Lord's name in vain.

Comment: The following appears to be a usage from 1964: ....."as I was chirping to Tom just before his bridge debut, “ ***thank bog there are young***, jukes like ol' Rawn Pudgey etc., the load is no longer bustin.... " https://books.google.it/books?id=b3EoAQAAMAAJ&q=%22thank+bog%22&dq=%22thank+bog%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_xueps_LTAhXD1BoKHVi5ANMQ6AEIODAF

Comment: Could be borrowed from Russian (or another Slavic language)?

Comment: There are no instances at all in COHA (corpus of Historical American English). "Bog" is Russian for God, so I immediately thought of two science fiction books where the slang has a Russian element: _A Clockwork Orange_ by Anthorny Burgess (1962), and _The Moon is a Harsh Mistress_ by Robert Heinlein (1966). I don't know whether the phrase occurs in either though.

Comment: @ColinFine That's almost certainly it!  I've read both many times (and watch *A Clockwork Orange* more times than I can count).  I'm sure its one or the other, although I believe *A Clockwork Orange*  has more pop-culture weight, so I'm leaning toward that.

Comment: "Bog" as a replacement for "God" does appear in the [Nadsat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:A_Clockwork_Orange) usage within *A Clockwork Orange*.

Comment: `But I thank dear Bog...` is also a quote from [*The Moon is a Harsh Mistress*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HtuRSsAb2fEC&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=the+moon+is+a+harsh+mistress+thank+bog&source=bl&ots=qDyREuHD6W&sig=r3rp8MVfQPrx5zN1uhmb63tuKJE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigi9PZtvLTAhUG4SYKHV0mDOUQ6AEISjAG#v=onepage&q=the%20moon%20is%20a%20harsh%20mistress%20thank%20bog&f=false)

Comment: A Clockwork Orange (Anthony Burgess) - ***Nadsat Glossary***  -  ***Bog -  God*** - http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/clockworkorange/terms.html - What inspired the language of A Clockwork Orange?http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/05/language-of-a-clockwork-orange/

Comment: Huh. Without knowing the Russian, I would have assumed it was from the mirror-image of god (d=b), especially as the earliest example in print uses a lower-case "b".

Answer (score 1):

***Bog*** appears to be the English version of the [Russian word](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-russian/god) **Бог** which means **God**.